# File won't open in r

Tags: r, file, syntax-error, filechooser

I'm new to using R and thought I had opening files down but alas, I am struggling. This is the error message I am receiving:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'reading.txt': No such file or directory
```

This is what I've been running and it all falls apart when I get to reading the table

```
file.choose()
ch3data<-read.delim("/Users/mackenziedawes/Desktop/Stats Class /Week 5: ch 3/reading.txt")
#set.wd()
ch3data<-read.table("reading.txt", header=T)
```

Comment: If you want to use `file.choose`, try something like `ch3data<-read.table(file.choose(), header=T)` or be sure to capture the value with something like `my_path <- file.choose(); read.table(mypath, header=T)`.

Comment: (1) it's `setwd()`, not `set.wd()`. (2) When you can't open a file as you think should be present, check everything in the path. The path and filename are both case-sensitive (when not on windows) and sensitive to spaces. Since you're using a full absolute path, it could be that the directory doesn't exist, you don't have permissions on the directory, the file doesn't exist, or the file is "locked" by some other process (though I don't think macos does that?).

Comment: A more normal way to set this up is like so (this assumes you've provided valid paths). First, set your working directory: `setwd("/Users/mackenziedawes/Desktop/Stats Class /Week 5: ch 3")`  and then `ch3data<-read.table("reading.txt", header=T)`. Specifying a working directory means subsequent paths can be specified relative to that directory, rather than providing an absolute path. Useful when you need to work with multiple files in a single folder. As MrFlick notes, `file.choose()` is a good way to verify you have the correct path if you're unsure.